# Dúvida com versão do Microsoft .NET Framework asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Dúvida, estou usando a versão errada?
Na imagem mostra o Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

No meu servidor de hospedagem informa isso:

ASP, Asp.NET 3.5, Asp.NET 4.0, Asp.NET 4.5
Extensões Ajax para Asp.NET
HTML, CSS, XML e JavaScript
MVC3, MVC4, MVC5
Painel de Controle Plesk em português 
Suporte a Flash, WML e WAP

Após subir um site feito em asp.net mvc, eu tenho uma mensagem de erro: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Então eu fiz um site com apenas 1 controller e gerei a view, adicionei no web.config :

Para me mostra o erro e subir os arquivos para o diretório principal httpdocs, agora me gera uma mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No route esta assim:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebSiteTeste
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

no Controller:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebSiteTeste.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

no index:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

No web config:

```html
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Mostra o codigo do cotroller, e as url, aparentemente o erro é simplesmente Not Found, ou seja não encontrou o caminho.

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen, 

Eu fiz a criação de um projeto com apenas 1 controler é uma Views sem acesso a banco, só a pagina inicial padrão , fiz a publicação e subir os arquivos, neste caso falta alguma coisa?

Comment: Cara mostra a url o controller/action e route config

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen, atualizei a pergunta com vários detalhes, veja se esta de acordo. agradeço

Comment: O erro da sua imagem é o 404 e em sua pergunta você diz que é o `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.`. Poderia especificar melhor seu problema?

Comment: @Randrade, acho que você não leu direito a pergunta, veja isso: "Após subir um site feito em asp.net mvc, eu tenho uma mensagem de erro: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
Então eu fiz um site com apenas 1 controller e gerei a view, adicionei no web.config :
Para me mostra o erro e subir os arquivos para o diretório principal httpdocs, agora me gera uma mensagem de erro:"

Comment: @itasouza Li sim. Mas o erro que você postou não é o 403. O problema do erro de agora está na minha resposta abaixo. Já sobre o 403 não tem como te ajudar sem as informações dele.

Comment: @itasouza qual url deu o erro?

Comment: Vou te explicar melhor, eu fiz o site completo em asp.net mvc, fiz a criação de um diretório virtual é subir os arquivos, ai eu tive o erro 403, como eu não sabia o porque, então eu fiz um site comum com apenas 1 controller, gerei a view e adicionei algumas configurações no web.config e ai me gerou outro erro (404) que esta na minha pergunta, eu fiz as alterações da sua resposta, deu certo.

Comment: Se ainda tiver recebendo o erro 403, abra uma pergunta específica sobre isso. Várias vezes o problema está na hospedagem

Comment: @Randrade, acho que o problema é este : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107413/como-configurar-rotas-quando-a-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-na-esta-na-raiz-do-servidor-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito simples.
Você está chamando o controller Home em sua `RouteConfig`, mas o nome do seu controller é `DefaultController`.

Basta alterar o nome de seu controller ou o nome em seu `RouteConfig`.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
```

ou

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

> Da forma que está seu código sua aplicação não encontra o controller, por isso o erro 404 (not found).