# Como configurar rotas quando a aplicação não esta na raiz do servidor asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Localmente o meu site tem a seguinte rota padrão é tudo funciona:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Projeto.WEB.Celular
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
}
```

Mais o meu site não esta na pasta raiz do servidor, eu tenho uma pasta virtual com o nome website, ficando assim:

http://www.teste.com.br/website

Desta forma quando eu vou fazer um acesso a uma página o redirecionamento fica apontando para a pasta raiz, e deveria vim o nome da pasta antes:

http://www.sistemaguardiao.com.br/” falta a pasta”/RecuperaSenha

Exemplo:

```html
@model Generico.Dominio.TB_USUARIO


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@Html.Partial("_navbarPrincipal")
@Html.Partial("_PartialMensagens")


<div class="container droppedHover">


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.login, new { placeholder = "endereço de e-mail", @class = "form-control input-lg "})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.login)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.senha, new { placeholder = "password", @class = "form-control input-lg", type = "password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.senha)
            </div>
        </div>



        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" type="submit" name="opcao" value="pesquisar" >   Login...</button>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "RecuperaSenha")" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning ">
                    Recuperar Senha
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


}


</div>
```

web confing:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>



  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conexao"
         connectionString="Server=PC-ESTUDO\SQLEXPRESS;Database=teste;User Id=teste;Password=123;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

  </system.web>



  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Como você está fazendo para criar os links nas suas *Views*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, eu adicionei na pergunta a página de login, veja o link que chama a RecuperaSenha, neste caso já vem sem a pasta "website"

Comment: E a hospedagem? Como é feita? No IIS ou num serviço dedicado de Website?

Comment: serviço dedicado, igual no meu exemplo : http://www.teste.com.br/website

Comment: Posso até dar uma resposta, mas teria que ter acesso ao `web.config` do diretório de cima.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Ok, você pode ter acesso, web.config do diretório de cima seria qual o que fica dentro da pasta Views ou que fica fora?

Comment: O do diretório raiz.

Comment: Existe 2 web config, um dentro do projeto logo acima do Global.asax e outro que fica logo a baixo, qual precisa?

Comment: O web.config logo abaixo.

Comment: adicionei na pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer sua aplicação funcionar em um subdiretório, altere seu `Web.config` para o seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conexao"
         connectionString="Server=PC-ESTUDO\SQLEXPRESS;Database=teste;User Id=teste;Password=123;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

  </system.web>
  </location>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Esta declaração:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

Faz com que as configurações neste ponto sejam usadas apenas pela aplicação do diretório raiz. Configurações específicas de subdiretórios passam a ser consideradas.

Note que a seção não vale para o arquivo todo. `<runtime>` não entra na seção.

Comment: a resposta é isso? <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">?

Comment: É. Coloquei o exemplo completo.

Comment: sim, eu vi, mais apenas 1 linha era a resposta, Esta resposta não vai ajudar muitas pessoas, visto que a única diferença esta em 1 linha que nei foi explicado o porque dela, mais tudo bem, eu agradeço a sua boa vontade. Eu estou aprendendo na raça pura, sozinho mais estou indo.

Comment: Melhorei a resposta. Creio que agora ficará mais claro para mais pessoas o que deve ser feito. Peço desculpas pela incompletude.